# WordPressのWelcartプラグインでフックを設定したのに反映されない。

Tags: php

ワードプレスのwelcartを設置しています。

下記の記述をし、
買い物を続けるのボタンを押すと、
指定するページに遷移するようなフックを設定しました。

しかしながら、設定は反映されず、通常のページの遷移になります。
下記の記述で不備はございますか？

```
// 買い物を続ける ————————————————————————————–
add_filter(‘usces_filter_cart_prebutton’, ‘my_cart_prebutton’);
function my_cart_prebutton(){
return ‘ onclick=”location.href=’url’”‘;
}
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

リターン値が文字列として成立してませんがPHP側でエラー出てませんか？

```
return 'onclick="location.href='http://url'"';
```

↓

```
return 'onclick="location.href=\'http://url\'"';
```

またはこんな↓感じで工夫する。

```
$jsevent = 'onclick="{{js}}";'
$js = "location.href='http://url'";
return str_replace('{{js}}', $js, $jsevent);
```